# How to poll for latest product build from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, testing, automation, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have multiconfiguration automated testsuite project working in automated fashion periodically,
but the it runs with same product build everytime.
I want it to run only when there is new build on a given
link.

Problem:
Polling the scm is one option but,
My SCM is set to git which contains my testing automation suite,
and I need to poll svn to check for new builds, and I don't know if or how to setup multiple scm in
single project

How can I achieve this ??

Comment: Please elaborate more! add the error details or a sample,  If you have tried and not working. 
If I understand you correctly - You want to invoke a Job polling from Git if there is a change on SVN?

Comment: I want to Poll a nfs-share for Latest Build and trigger testsuite automation if found new build, testsuite is in Git